# how to define custom helper in default.ctp file?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-1.2

i created custom helper to build dynamic menu and i need to use this helper in all my site pages  so i put the code to show menu in element and include it in  default.ctp like this

```
   <?php echo $this->element('menu'); ?>
```

,, but the default.ctp not defined the helper so how to define this helper in all views it give me this errors

```
Notice (8): Undefined variable: data [APP\views\elements\menu.ctp, line 5]

Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP\views\helpers\tree.php, line 28]
```

**helpers/tree.php**

```
<?php
class TreeHelper extends Helper
{

    var $tab = "  ";
    var $helpers = array('Html');

    // Main Function
    function show($name, $data, $style='')
    {
        list($modelName, $fieldName) = explode('/', $name);
        if ($style=='options') {
            $output = $this->selecttag_options_array($data, $modelName, $fieldName, $style, 0);
        } else {
            //$style='';
            $output = $this->list_element($data, $modelName, $fieldName, $style, 0);
        }
        return $this->output($output);
    }

    // This creates a list with optional links attached to it
    function list_element($data, $modelName, $fieldName, $style, $level)
    {
        $tabs = "\n" . str_repeat($this->tab, $level * 2);
        $li_tabs = $tabs . $this->tab;

        $output = $tabs. "<ul>";
        foreach ($data as $key=>$val)
        {
            $output .= $li_tabs . "<li>".$this->style_print_item($val[$modelName], $modelName, $style);
            if(isset($val['children'][0]))
            {
                $output .= $this->list_element($val['children'], $modelName, $fieldName, $style, $level+1);
                $output .= $li_tabs . "</li>";
            }
            else
            {
                $output .= "</li>";
            }
        }
        $output .= $tabs . "</ul>";
        return $output;
    }

    // this handles the formatting of the links if there necessary
    function style_print_item($item, $modelName, $style='')
    {
        switch ($style)
        {
            case "link":
                $output = $this->Html->link($item['name'], "view/".$item['id']);
            break;

            case "admin":
                $output = $item['name'];
                $output .= $this->Html->link(" edit", "edit/".$item['id']);
                $output .= " ";
                $output .= $this->Html->link(" del", "delete/".$item['id']);
            break;

            default:
                $output = $item['name'];
        }
    return $output;
    }

    // recursively reduces deep arrays to single-dimensional arrays
    // $preserve_keys: (0=>never, 1=>strings, 2=>always)
    // Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php#77671
    function array_flatten($array, $preserve_keys = 1, &$newArray = Array())
    {
          foreach ($array as $key => $child)
          {
            if (is_array($child))
            {
                  $newArray =& $this->array_flatten($child, $preserve_keys, $newArray);
            }
            elseif ($preserve_keys + is_string($key) > 1)
            {
                  $newArray[$key] = $child;
            }
            else
            {
                  $newArray[] = $child;
            }
          }
          return $newArray;
    }

    // for formatting selecttag options into an associative array (id, name)
    function selecttag_options_array($data, $modelName, $fieldName, $style, $level)
    {
        // html code does not work here
        // tried using " " and it didn't work
        $tabs = "-";

        foreach ($data as $key=>$val)
        {
            $output[] = array($val[$modelName]['id'] => str_repeat($tabs, $level*2) . ' ' . $val[$modelName]['name']);

            if(isset($val['children'][0]))
            {
                $output[] = $this->selecttag_options_array($val['children'], $modelName, $fieldName, $style, $level+1);
            }
        }

        $output = $this->array_flatten($output, 2);
        return $output;
    }
}
?>
```

**elements/menu.ctp**

```
<!-- This will turn the section name into a link -->
<h3>Basic hierarchical list with name as link</h3>
<?php echo $tree->show('Section/name', $data, 'link'); ?>
```

Comment: How do you define $data in menu.ctp?

Comment: i used this tut http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/MrRio/2006/09/24/threaded-lists

Comment: I think that to use the helper from this tutorial you will have to create a controller. Here is another tutorial that might be more appropriate for your task: [link](http://articles.classoutfit.com/2009/11/cakephp-dynamic-navigation-bars/)

Comment: but this tutorial without database,,ok i use find in all controllers to display the menu but i have one problem,,the menu link changed from http://localhost/tet/sections/view/15 to http://localhost/tet/articles/view/15 when use find in articles_controller

Answer (score 1):

You have to define it in your AppController, located in the root of your app directory (and if it's not there, just create a file called `app_controller.php` You can use the file with the same name in the Cake core directory as a template for this file.

When you have your app_controller, add the following

```
var $helpers = array('Tree');
```

You might want to add some other standard helpers like Html, Form and Javascript in here as well. All the helpers that are in AppController will be available to all of your controllers.